# jQuery Load an external script rich PHP file into local page

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I've searched the entire web for a clear answer but haven't found one yet.

I have this site:

www.helixagent.com/todo/

and I want to load that entire site into a portlet in my main index page.

I tried an iFrame approach but it fails to load the site correctly. The styles and javascript files don't get loaded (i think)

Is there a way to make a portal that mimics a new browser page and load the content exactly as it would if it was directly accessed via the url bar?

Comment: The iframe approach does load the css and js correctly. Can you show the html/js you used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s possible to perform [cross-domain requests using jQuery](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/cross-domain-requests-with-jquery/).

Simply include [this file](http://github.com/jamespadolsey/jQuery-Plugins/raw/master/cross-domain-ajax/jquery.xdomainajax.js) after loading jQuery, and then you can do funky stuff like:

```
$('html').load('http://helixagent.com/todo/');
```

Note that this of course won’t load the embedded CSS and JS files. You’ll need to use an `iframe` for that:

```
$(function() {
 $('body').append('<iframe src="http://www.helixagent.com/todo/" />');
});
```

Live example: http://jsbin.com/uruka

Comment: i looked over at the site you provided. I think this is the term I was looking for but really new to this stuff and feel embarrassed to ask for help. But i'm not familiar with the terms so thank you.

How would i get something like this set up and running? the site didn't really offer much help to someone who didn't know what they where talking about when implementing the code...

Comment: so i did what you said, now i place the sample you gave after the DOM is ready? i can rename the 'html' to maybe '#todo' and plave a <div id='todo'></div> where i want it to load?

Comment: The answer to both questions would be ‘yes’.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example using jQuery and iframe:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#somediv').html("<iframe src='http://www.helixagent.com/todo/'></iframe>");
});
```

This should be placed inside the `<head>` tag of your page and it will load the entire site with all the js and css too into a div.

Comment: www.helixagent.com/drag/ this is the site with the portlets. In one of them I would like to load www.helixagent.com/todo/ do I just place the code you provided in the DIV that belongs to the portlet I would like have my page load into?

Comment: I have this snippet

            <li class="widget color-blue" id="widget3">  
                <div class="widget-head">
                    <h3>Widget 3 title</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="widget-content">
 $('#widget-content').html("<iframe src='http://www.helixagent.com/todo/'></iframe>");
                </div>
            </li>

that is the div layout for one portlet in a column.

you same #somediv, what does this link to? I'm sorry to ask but can you explain please.

thank you

Comment: oh, i tried you example but its not loading anything. I have the site setup like this for the porlets.
<html>
<head>
<title>
CSS scripts
Javascripts
--jquery
</head>
<div>
<div content>
<div todo></div>
</div>
</div>
Javascript 
--jquery UI
--portlet.js
</body>
</html>

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at using [Server Side Includes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes).